# What is the necessity of the Implicit Grant redirect URI?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

It seems like in the Implicit Grant OAuth flow, the redirect URI is necessary and it must be

- different from the origin URI
- on the same domain as the origin URI

Why is the redirect URI necessary? Specifically what security attack does it prevent? Why can't the origin just have javascript that listens for the token response instead of receiving it from the redirect URI?

Answer (score 0):

One way the redirect URI improves security is that the redirect URI needs to be pre-defined on the OAuth server for the client application.  This prevents client applications from redirecting the logged in user to any URI on the Internet; the app can only redirect to a pre-approved URI.  So if someone steals a client ID and creates a new app with that client ID they will need to use the same redirect URI.